# Google Maps API KML layer limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I need to display a large number of KML files on a Google Maps API map, based on certain conditions.

When I try adding these KML files, I end up reaching some limitation with Google Maps and KML layers.

[image]

I've tried using shortened URLs, PHP scripts, shortened URLs AND PHP scripts but nothing seems to have fixed the issue, and I still hit the limit within seconds...

Comment: I highly recommend https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3 from Geocodezip, who is also a SO user.

Comment: GeoXML has been a godsend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GeoXML, I was able to add all the required KMLs to the map successfully!
https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3

Thanks to Tony Miller for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions):

> **Number of KML layers**
>
> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will appear on the map, and an error will be reported in your web browser's JavaScript console. The limit is based on a combination of the number of KMLLayer classes created and the total length of all the URLs used to create those layers. Each new KMLLayer you create will take up a portion of the limit for the layer and a further portion of the limit depending on the length of the URL where the KML file was loaded from. Consequently, the number of layers you can add will vary by application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit. If you still hit the limit, use a URL shortner (such as https://goo.gl) to shorten the KML URLs. **Alternatively, create a single KML file consisting of NetworkLinks to the individual KML URLs.**

Comment: Network links won't work for what I'm doing... I need certain KMLs to load depending on certain conditions.